# SQL unusual query, find max deltas between consecutive elements

Tags: mysql, sql

I've met an interesting problem.
I have a table of workers' ids' and days of their visits. Here is dump:

```
CREATE TABLE `pp` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `day` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `key` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
) 

INSERT INTO `pp` VALUES 
   (1,1,'1'),
   (1,20,'2'),
   (1,50,'3'),
   (1,70,'4'),
   (2,1,'5'),
   (2,120,'6'),
   (2,90,'7'),
   (1,90,'8'),
   (2,100,'9');
```

So I need to find workers which have missed more than 50 days at least once. For example, if worker visited at 5th, 95th, 96th, 97th day, if we look at deltas, we can see that the largest delta (90) is more than 50, so we should include this worker into result.
The problem is how do I efficiently find deltas between visits of different workers?

I can't even imagine how to work with mysql tables as consequent arrays of data.

So we need to separate day values for different workers, sort them and then find max deltas for each. But how? Is there any way to, for example, enumerate sorted arrays in sql?

Comment: What does `day` represent? If it's the day of the year, can one record be `365` and the next be `1`? Or can you ***guarantee*** that a subsequent value is always higher than a pervious value?

Comment: worker 2 visited at day 1, day 120, and then back at day 90?

Comment: @Dems, that was just the matter of simplification, in order to focus on the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way I used to cope with such problems:

```
SELECT distinct t3.id  FROM
(SELECT t1.id, t1.day, MIN(t2.day) nextday
FROM pp t1
JOIN pp t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.day<t2.day
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.day
HAVING nextday-t1.day >50) t3
```

(**EDIT** this version is slightly better)
This finds all the IDs for which there is a delta > 50. (I assumed that this is what you're after)

To see it working: [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87955/3)

To find the max deltas:

```
SELECT t3.id, MAX(t3.nextday-t3.day)  FROM
(SELECT t1.id, t1.day, MIN(t2.day) nextday
FROM pp t1
JOIN pp t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.day<t2.day
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.day) t3
GROUP BY t3.id
```

The logic behind is to find the "next" item, whatever that means. As this is an ordered attribute, the next item can be defined as having the lowest value among those rows that have the value larger than the one examined... Then you join the "next" values to the original values, conpute the delta, and return only those that are applicable. If you need the other columns too, just do a JOIN on the outer select to the original table.

I'm not sure if this is the best solution regarding perfirmance, but I only wrote queries for one-off reports, with which I could afford the query to run for a while.

There is one semantic error though, that can arise: if somebody was present on the 1st, 2nd and 3rd days, but **never after**, this does not find the absence. To overcome this, you could add a special row with `UNION`ing a select to the tables specifying tomorrow's day count for all `ID`s, but that would make this query disgusting enough not to try writing it down...

Comment: Brilliant! That was what I was searching for. I've tried the same approach, but without `MIN(t2.day)` - this was essential. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

**edited:**

```
SELECT t.id, t.day1, t.day2 FROM (
  SELECT p1.id, p1.day day1, p2.day day2 FROM pp p1
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM pp ORDER BY day) p2
      ON p1.id = p2.id AND p1.day < p2.day
   GROUP BY p1.id, p1.day
  )  t
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING MAX(day2 - day1) >= 50
```

Comment: Will this be significantly quicker than my earlier proposal? Also why the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: It should be INNER ;) ...changed.

Comment: Sorry for the many questions, but you seem to be credible to answer them :) Does having an ORDER BY clause in the subselect in the JOIN make it quicker, by altering the execution plan? Shouldn't then the other `pp` table in the JOIN have it too to force a MERGE JOIN?

Comment: The ORDER BY clause in subselect does not make it quicker; it needed to sort records in specific manner. The other `pp` does not need sorting.

Comment: Well, are you sure that this one is correct? If one visited on 1st day, on 20th day, on 40th day and on 60th day, the MAX would give us maximum `p2.day - p1.day`, which is 60-1 = 59. But  the largest delta is 20. It seems to me that generally in this task order by is senseless. What you've probably missed is selecting `MIN(p2.day)`, which is crucial here.

Comment: @alex_jordan Yes. I have missed this condition, thanks for this notice. I added one more query version.

Comment: @Devart, Interesting, I like it, it looks hacky because of replacement of `min` with taking the first element in the ordered group.

Comment: @Devart, Interesting, I like it, it looks hacky because of replacement of `min` with taking the first element in the ordered group.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be a solution:

```
select distinct pp.id
from pp
where pp.day-(select max(day)
              from pp pp2
              where
                pp2.id=pp.id and
                pp2.day<pp.day)>=50
```

(since days are not ordered by key, i'm not searching for the previous key but for the max day  before current day)